# Read a file and produce files based on the number of columns inside the original file

Tags: c#

How can I read a file and produce files based on the number of columns inside the original file in C#

original file:

text1
text2

**Col**

```
col1 col2
1     11
2     22
3     33
4     44
```

Output files:
file1

text1
text2

**Col**

```
col1 
1     
2    
3     
4
```

file2:

text1
text2

**Col**

```
 col2
 11
 22
 33
 44
```

Comment: How are columns delimited? Do their column names come after empty line following word `Col`?

Comment: What code have you tried and why is it failing (ie, what is the error message or incorrect output)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the columns are delimited by space characters, this code should work:

```
        string filePath = @"C:\input.txt";
        string outputDirectory = @"C:\";
        string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

        // Replace multiple spaces with a single space character.
        for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length; i++ )
        {
            allLines[i] = Regex.Replace(allLines[i], @"\s+", " ");
        }

        // Check how many columns there are.
        int columns = 0;
        if (allLines.Length > 0)
            columns = allLines[0].Split().Length;

        var linesValues = allLines.Select(l => l.Split());

        // Write each column to a separate file "output1.txt" ... "outputN.txt".
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder newTable = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string[] values in linesValues)
            {
                newTable.Append(values[i] + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            File.WriteAllText(outputDirectory + "output" + i + ".txt", newTable.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);    after this I am getting the error "The name 'File' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @Dallag You have to add `using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` to the header of the class.